# How to concatenate variable in Oracle like dot "." function in php

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
declare
tgl RENC_DITSEK.TGL_INPUT%TYPE;
thn varchar(10) := :new.tahun + 1;
BEGIN

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO tgl FROM DUAL;
  IF UPDATING ('TARGET_2') THEN
     INSERT INTO NOTE_LOG VALUES(:NEW.PKP,'',:NEW.INDIKATOR,'Target Tahun ' ???? thn,'','','',tgl,'','0');
  END IF;
END;
```

In the above trigger body, I need to join the `thn` value with `'Target Tahun'

If using php there just add the dot symbol like `'Target Tahun '.thn`, but I need to do this with SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL concatenation operator is `||`, so you need to use:

```
'Target Tahun '||thn
```

Comment: or function `concat('aaa','bbb')`